# Why are some words in a sentence put in parentheses despite being essential to the sentence's meaning?

Tags: sentence, parentheses

I've come upon many sentences that have put parentheses around words that are essential to the sentence's meaning. I was wondering why these words are written like this? Here is an example: "But for some reason the (boys) make us laugh." Why is "boys" put in parentheses?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Where did you see such a sentence? I cannot think of a reason why anyone would want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quotation from MTV's original [disclaimer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9oJriosW6E) for the show 'Beavis and Butthead'

> Beavis and Butt-head are not real.  They are stupid cartoon people completely made up by this Texas guy who we hardly even know. Beavis and Butt-head are dumb, crude, thoughtless, ugly, sexist, self-destructive fools. But for some reason, the little weinerheads make us laugh.

In most online versions of this the expression in parentheses, (*boys*), replaces *little weinerheads*; presumably somebody somewhere thought (or pretended to think, as a joke) that *little weinerheads* was too vulgar to put before their readers.

In academic contexts square brackets [] are usually used to acknowledge alterations to an original; but this particular edit is unlikely to appear in an academic context.

Comment: So then the "many sentences" as mentioned in the OP is actually only this single usage?

Comment: @Cascabel It's the only one OP gives. I have in fact seen other instances of edits marked with parens instead of square brackets, but I have no idea how to find one in a hurry.